# jsf 2.2 managed bean injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, cdi, jsf-2.2

I am developing Java EE Application in NetBeans IDE. The app contains EJB and WAR containers like down bellow:

**EAR:**

```
- EJB & JPA 
- WAR (JSF 2.2)
```

**Communication:**

JPA <-> EJB

EJB <-> WAR

My WAR container contains .xhtml pages and 3 JSF ManagedBeans:

```
UserManagedBean
UploadManagedBean
SubjectManagedBean
```

When the user is logged in, the **UserManagedBean**, which is session scoped, holds the data of current user's session.

**Issue**

At some point, I want to use some values (or even object) from class **UserManagedBean** in another class (**SubjectManagedBean**). But when I try to inject this managed bean into another I got:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

**These are classes**

UserManagedBean:

```
package com.elearningjj.jsfbeans;

import com.elearningjj.beans.UserStatelessBeanLocal;
import com.elearningjj.entities.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("userManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    /* Instance of User's business logic */
    @EJB
    UserStatelessBeanLocal userStateless;


    /* User model attr */
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean isActiveSession;

    /* Singleton pattern, holding data for model User */
    private static User userModel = new User();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public UserManagedBean() {

    }

    /**
     * Getter for username
     * @return username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for password
     * @return password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for active session
     * @return true/false
     */
    public boolean getIsActiveSession() {
        return isActiveSession;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for username
     * @param username 
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for password
     * @param password 
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for active session
     * @param active 
     */
    public void setActiveSession(boolean active) {
        this.isActiveSession = active;
    }

    /* Ovaj metod ce se koristiti kasnije */
    public static FacesContext getCurrentInstance() {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    }

    /* Ovaj metod ce se koristiti kasnije */
    protected static void setCurrentInstance(FacesContext context) {
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the current active instance of User and it is used 
     * to pass the data model to backing bean. If user instance is not yet 
     * created it creates a new one.
     * 
     * @return userModel
     */
    public static User getInstance() {
        if (userModel == null)
            userModel = new User();
        return userModel;
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked by the user on login.xhtml page. When user submit
     * the form, the server side is checking for the data than sending it to 
     * backing bean in order to check whether user exist in the database.
     * 
     * @return response string
     */
    public String getLoginResponse() throws NullPointerException {

        String response = "";

        /* check whether the data is set on the server side */
        if (username != null && password != null) {

            /* Setting and prepairing data to being sent to backing bean */
            userModel.setUserName(username);
            userModel.setUserPassword(password);

            /* Check for user obj existance in the db and login or fail */
            if(userStateless.login(userModel) != null) {

                response = "You have been logged in sucessfully.";
                userModel = userStateless.login(userModel);
                ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); 

                try {
                    isActiveSession = true;
                    context.redirect("dashboard.xhtml");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UserManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else { 

                response = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }
        } 

        return response;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called on each of the restricted pages in order to check
     * whether the session is active or not. This will result either continuing 
     * or redirecting user to login page.
     */
    public void permission() {
        if(isActiveSession == false) {
            System.out.println("*** The user has no permission to visit this page. *** ");
            ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            try {
                context.redirect("login.xhtml");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("*** The session is still active. User is logged in. *** ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroys the current user's session
     */
    public void sessionDestroy() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        isActiveSession = false;
        try {
            context.redirect("index.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

SubjectManagedBean:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.elearningjj.jsfbeans;

import com.elearningjj.beans.SubjectStatelessBeanLocal;
import com.elearningjj.entities.Subject;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("subjectManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SubjectManagedBean implements Serializable{

    private String subjectCode;
    private String subjectName;

    @Inject
    UserManagedBean userManagedBean;

    @EJB
    private SubjectStatelessBeanLocal subjectStatelessBean;


    /**
     * Creates a new instance of SubjectManagedBean
     */
    public SubjectManagedBean() {
    }

    /**
     * Getter for subject code
     * @return subjectCode
     */
    public String getSubjectCode() {
        return subjectCode;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for subject code
     * @param subjectCode 
     */
    public void setSubjectCode(String subjectCode) {
        this.subjectCode = subjectCode;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for subject name
     * @return subjectName
     */
    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    /**
     * Seter for subject name
     * @param subjectName 
     */
    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public void addSubject(){
        Subject obj = new Subject();
        obj.setSubjectCode(subjectCode);
        obj.setSubjectName(subjectName);
        subjectStatelessBean.addSubject(obj);
        /* If I even try to use static method from userManagedBean it throws me an error */
        /* System.out.println("Test: " + UserManagedBean.getInstance().get.. */

    }

}
```

**Note**:

Please, see *addSubject* method in SubjectManagedBean class.

**Question**

What is the programming best practice for injecting UserBean into another? Should I use @Inject, @ManagedProperty, etc..

I look forward to seeing your comments.

Thank you.

**Update**

*Solved:*

I've change the @ManagedBean to @Named annotation and added the enterprise context to my scopes instead of standard.

I've used **@Inject** to import my jsf managed bean into another.

Comment: what container are you deploying to? Do you have beans.xml files in your EJB, WAR packages? How is this whole thing deployed?  Please provide the full stack trace from the 500 error.

Comment: Hi John, my whole app is running on Glassfish 4.0 app server and I dont have beans.xml. Everything works fine until I try to inject jsf managed bean into another so I think my problem is rather how to inject it properly. The glassfish throws an http 500 error saying that Subject entity cannot be casted to Subject enity which doesn't have any sense. As soon as I uncomment the injection my app is running properly again.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace here, as part of the question. Describing the stacktrace isn't as useful

Comment: I've solved the problem (_post is updated_). Thanks for your reply.